# MAC OS X difference between "open APP.app" and "APP.app/content/MacOs/APP" shell scripts

Tags: node.js, macos, shell, terminal, electron

Somehow I get a problem, if I call an application twice or several times but only one instance should be running (which is desired).

First some (probably necessary) background information:

- working on MAC OS X El Capitan (10.11.6)
- I've got an Application made by node.js, electron and build by "npm build -m" (let's call it APP.app)
- I installed the application App.app into program-folder by opening the built dmg-file and move it into the program-folder
- Then I start the application App.app by click on the App.app-icon in program-folder
- The application starts with a visible Window and also has an hidden background process running
- If I close the visible Window, the App.app-Icon remains in the dock (which is okay, since the background-process is still running)
- Now (and this is the difference to the windows build and running in windows), if I click again on the App.app-Icon in the program-folder, I only get a focus on the already running application INSTEAD of opening the window and close the old application (I can see te focus switch/activation by the switching menu name beside the apple-logo on top of the screen; it becomes "App")
- the closing of the previous running instance is defined in electron code in the init-method as follows:

  ```
      var shouldQuit = app.makeSingleInstance(function (commandLine, workingDirectory) {
      console.info('starting new instance');
      initInternal(commandLine);
      // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.
      var windows = options.closeWindowsOnRestart ? Browser.getAllWindows() : appWindows.slice();
      windows.forEach(function (val, index) {
          val.close();
      });
      readyCallback();
  });
  ```

So, I did some homework and could figure out following:

- my App.app-icon-click should look something like `open /Applications/App.app`
- with this, I get the same problem as descriped above if I call it again (it only focusses the already opened window)
- Now comes the funny part. If I open the application by calling directly `/Applications/App.app/content/MacOS/App.app` the old application-instance is closed and new App.app-application is started
- I read through `open`-manual and could figure out, that if I use the `-n`-flag, the application starts succesful a new instance, too. (`open /Applications/App.app -n`)

**I was wondering WHY? Do you have any clues? What is the difference between open and directly call of the application?**

I suggest that the info.pklist in App.app-package is making the open-call different to the direct call of App.app.

BTW:
Unfortunately I already tried to add try-catch-blocks to debug the problem, but `open` does not give an output to terminal, it just opens the call whereas the direct call does not throw an error and everything works fine.
Anyway, I believe it's more a MAC OS X problem than an App.app-problem.

Hopefully there's somebody with same problems and a solution for me

Don't hesitate to ask for more details, if needed.

Comment: nobody can tell me the difference of open and just call the application in app/Content/MacOS/app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Short Version:***

- `open` starts the application with the LaunchService (and  possible
  added launch-parameters in info.plist)
- whereas direct call of the
  application just starts the application iself without any other
  launch-options

***Long Version ***

I read through the open manual (`man open`; Source: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) and could figure out, that "the default application as determined via LaunchServices is used to open the specified files" if you click on an item.

So I read through the LaunchService-documentation and could figure out following:

> "Opening Items by File-System Reference [...] default way:
>       If the designated item is an application:     [...]
>           If the application is already running, it is activated (brought to the front of the screen) and sent an 'rapp' (“reopen
>   application”) Apple event."

(Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCTasks/LSCTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH203-TP9)

This reflects exactly my watching that if I click on the icon the second time, the app is just focussed/activated.

Thus I need the possibility to tell the application to open a new instance (oapp-event) instead of activating the already opened application (rapp-event)

Further reading lead me to following informations:

> "Launch Options When opening an application (whether by itself or to
>   open one or more documents or URLs), you can specify various launch
>   options to control the manner in which it is launched or activated.
>   These can include: [...] Whether to launch a new instance of the
>   application, even if another instance is already running"

(Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-BABBJHID)

Thus I only need to add the "launch option" to define, that a new instance should be created instead of activating the existing one. But there's not written what the launch-option for it is and how they will be applied to the application (I suggest it belongs into info.plist-file).

So at least this is the answer to my original question, so I posted it here.

open - starts the application with the Launch-Service (and the defined option-parameters in info.plist)
whereas direct call of the application just starts the application iself without any other launch-options